# Removing words from python lists?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am a complete noob in python and web scraping and have ran into some issues quite early. I have been able to scrape a Dutch news website their titles and splitting the words. Now my objective is to remove certain words from the results. For instance I don't want word like "het" and "om" in the list. Does anyone know how I can do this? (I'm using python requests and BeautifulSoup)

```html
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="http://www.nu.nl"
r=requests.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data=soup.find_all("span" , {"class": "title"})


for item in g_data:
    print item.text.split()
```

Comment: what do you mean words like `het` and `om`? What kind of words are they?

Comment: Hey Padraic, they are very common words like "it" and "because". In the end my objective is to keep only the important and special words for example words like "Franciscus" and "Google.".

Comment: You could use a set of words that you want to replace with empty strings but there is no way using BeautifulSoup to do what you want. That is more nltk than beautifulSoup

Comment: How would I have to do that? After I have installed nltk

Comment: Also maybe I forgot to say that I can manually put in the words I don't want. So the words don't have to come from a specific tool that recognises those kind of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In natural language processing, the term for excluding common words is called "stop words".

Do you want to preserve the order and count of each word, or do you just want the set of words that appear on the page?

If you just want the set of words that appear on the page, using sets is probably the way to go.  Something like the following might work:

```
# It's probably more common to define your STOP_WORDS in a file and then read
# them into your data structure to keep things simple for large numbers of those
# words.
STOP_WORDS = set([
    'het',
    'om'
])

all_words = set()
for item in g_data:
    all_words |= set(item.text.split())
all_words -= STOP_WORDS
print all_words
```

If, on the other hand, you care about the order, you could just refrain from adding stop words to your list.

```
words_in_order = []
for item in g_data:
    words_from_span = item.text.split()
    # You might want to break this out into its own function for modularity.
    for word in words_from_span:
        if word not in STOP_WORDS:
            words_in_order.append(word)
print words_in_order
```

If you don't care about order but you want frequency, you could create a dict (or defaultdict for convenience) of words to counts.

```
from collections import defaultdict
word_counts = defaultdict(int)
for item in g_data:
    # You might want to break this out into its own function for modularity.
    for word in item.text.split():
        if word not in STOP_WORDS:
            word_counts[word] += 1
for word, count in word_counts.iteritems():
    print '%s: %d' % (word, count)
```

Comment: Glad to help!  FYI -- if an answer on StackOverflow is helpful to you, you can accept it and/or upvote it.